# apache httpd mod_expires does not work when deflate is on

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4, httpd, mod-deflate

On a Debian Jessie installation, I manually installed wordpress and edited `.htaccess`, turning mod_expires on:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault modification
```

However, when I use Firefox Inspector to watch network traffic, I find all the js and css files return 200 OK with gzip-compressed content instead of HTTP 304.

Then I did some experiment.

1. I created an almost empty (incompressible) file named `foobar.css` and browse it in firefox. It returned `200 OK` with **uncompressed** data on the first time and `304 Not Modified` the second time.
2. I repeated the same content several times to create a large (compressible) file. This time the server returned `200 OK` with **compressed** data on the first time, the second time, the third time... Every time it returns the same content instead of the expected `304 Not Modified`.

I watched `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf` and found that `text/css` is deflated by default:

```
...
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
...
```

Can the two modules mod_expires and mod_deflate work at the same time? How should I configure them?

Terribly sorry for broken English.

EDIT:
I have found a workaround here:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023#c22
However, it is only a workaround. I think it's really a server bug.

Comment: Did you tried to remove file Etag ? What does say last modified header ?

Comment: Workaround found. It does modify header...

Comment: You should post your workaround as anwser then validate it, it would prevent post polution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023#c22

Just put the following line in `.htaccess` or httpd configuration file:

```
RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" '^"((.*)-gzip)"$' '"$1", "$2"'
```

Dirty, but effective. `;)`